# How to replace input substring in batch-file?

Tags: batch-file, input, substring

For example- I have a file example.txt, which on line 2 contains

```
abc?d
```

"abc" is my input. I want only "d" as a output with a batch-file.

I can use something like that

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" ^< "example.txt" ^| findstr "^\[\2]" ') do set "variable=%%b"
set variable=%variable:%input%=%
set variable=%variable:?=%
echo %variable%
```

But that doesn't work.

Please help !

Comment: You want to get what comes after the '?' on line 2 and put in %variable%, is that it?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean exactly? you need to specify precisely what you want to get a precise answer; at the moment your question is not quite clear...

Answer (score 0):

You need delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "input=abc"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" ^< "example.txt" ^| findstr "^\[\2]" ') do set "variable=%%b"
set variable=!variable:%input%=!
set variable=%variable:?=%
echo %variable%
```

`%variable:%anothervariable%=%` doesn't work, because it's interpreted as variable `%variable:%` plus string `anothervariable` plus variable `%=%`

it's also possible to delete everything before and including the questionmark (even without delayed expansion):

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" ^< "example.txt" ^| findstr "^\[\2]" ') do set "variable=%%b"
set variable=%variable:*?=%
echo %variable%
```

Another way without `for` (read first and second line):

```
<example.txt (
  set /p variable=
  set /p variable=
)
    set variable=%variable:*?=%
    echo %variable%
```

or with a bit more flexibility (again with the help of `for`):

```
set "lineNo=2"
<example.txt (for /L %%i in (1,1,%lineNo%) do set /p "variable=")
set variable=%variable:*?=%
echo %variable%
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried it and worked:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=?" %%a in ('find /n /v "" ^< "example.txt" ^| findstr "^\[\2]" ') do set variable=%%b
echo %variable%
```

Comment: Even simpler: `for /F "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=?" %%a in (example.txt) do set "variable=%%a" & goto break` and place `:break` label in next line.